# NSPredicate with multiple arguments and "AND behaviour"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function which fetches those objects from a particular entity that fulfill a specified criterion:

```
func fetchWithPredicate(entityName: String, argumentArray: [AnyObject]) -> [NSManagedObject] {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: argumentArray)

     do {
         return try self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
     } catch {
         let fetchError = error as NSError
         print(fetchError)
         return [NSManagedObject]()
     }

}
```

When I pass an array with multiple aguments (multiple attribute names and values) it seems that creates a query like this:

```
attributeName1 = value1 OR attributeName2 = value2 OR attributeName3 = value3 OR...
```

I would like to change these ORs for ANDs.

**EDIT:**

The problem was that it was only [replacing the first two items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202476/4688931) with "%K == %@".

So, I have to create a [NSCompoundPredicate to create a predicate dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202601/4688931).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create a predicate (with a variable number of expressions) dynamically, use `NSCompoundPredicate`, e.g.

```
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)
```

where `subPredicates` is a `[NSPredicate]` array, and each subpredicate
is created from the provided arguments in a loop with

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, value)
```

Something like this (untested):

```
func fetchWithPredicate(entityName: String, argumentArray: [NSObject])  -> [NSManagedObject]  {

    var subPredicates : [NSPredicate] = []
    for i in 0.stride(to: argumentArray.count, by: 2) {
        let key = argumentArray[i]
        let value = argumentArray[i+1]
        let subPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, value)
        subPredicates.append(subPredicate)
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 20):

In your example the `%K` and `%@` format tokens are replaced **only** by the first two items of the argument array, the other items are ignored.

You have to provide all format tokens to be replaced in the string for example

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@ AND %K == %@", argumentArray:["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"])
```

Comment: It is true, it was only replacing the first two items. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Swift 3

I found easiest way.

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key1 = %@ AND key2 = %@", value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a compound predicate. I'll give you the Objective-C syntax, I'll leave the translation to Swift as an exercise...

If your keys and values are in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *conds = @{ @"key1": @"value1", @"key2", @"value2" };

NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:conds.allKeys.length];

for (NSString *key in conds.allKeys)
{
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, conds[key]]];
}
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@ AND title = %@", argumentArray: ["id value", "title value"])
```