# How to use Dynamic Multiple NSPredicate from NSArray in Core data

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am fairly new to core data. I have database which contains articles with different categories. I want to fetch data from multiple categories, which can be selected by user on the fly. Now I have NSArray which contains selected multiple categories (count from 1 to n) I want to add predicate for selected categories but I'm not able to do so. as per my knowledge i have added for loop for adding categories in predicate but it is not working.

```
for i in 0...(catArray?.count)!-1 {
    let str = String(format:"catId = %@",(catArray?.object(at: i) as? NSNumber)!)
    predicateString = predicateString+str
}
let dP = NSPredicate(format:"%@",predicateString)
fetchedRequest.predicate=dP;
```

but app is crashing while fetching request.
Is there any other way to do it?
Please help me with this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use NSCompoundPredicate. Example e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202239/nspredicate-with-multiple-arguments-and-and-behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPredicate with multiple arguments and "AND behaviour"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202239/nspredicate-with-multiple-arguments-and-and-behaviour)

Comment: But is you want to select objects which have any category from the selected array then it is just `NSPredicate(format: "catId IN %@", catArray)`

Comment: Thank you @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select objects which have any category from the given array 
a simple predicate is sufficient:

```
NSPredicate(format: "catId IN %@", catArray)
```

*Remark:* Never use `String(format:)` to build predicates dynamically,
because almost surely the quoting and escaping will be wrong.
Use only `NSPredicate(format:)` and, if necessary, `NSCompoundPredicate`.