# FetchRequest: Multiple values for a predicate?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a pretty simple FetchRequest to fetch items where "priority" = "High".

```
    @FetchRequest(entity: TaskItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.createdDate, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", "High")) var taskItems: FetchedResults<TaskItem>
```

How can I modify this request to include items that are "High" and "Medium"

Comment: Construct a compound predicate? Did you look to see how predicates work? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789

Comment: You mean *items that are "High" **or** "Medium"*

Comment: @Vadian: yes, i think he means it because he wrote "include items"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@ or priority == %@", "High", "Medium")
```

another solution can be found here: [NSPredicate with multiple arguments and "AND behaviour"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202239/nspredicate-with-multiple-arguments-and-and-behaviour)

Comment: @Willke: if he replaces his predicate with mine,..why shouldn't this help?! that was his question:  How can I modify this request to include items that are "High" and "Medium"

Comment: "did you try this?" is a question, not an answer.

Comment: ah ok, i will change that, thank you